# Create a row using group off arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say we have an Array that looks like this
(example)

```
Array1 = [Data_A,Data_B];
Array2 = [Data_1,Data_2,Data_3];
```

and I have a table that looks like this

[image]

How can I achieve this?

[image]

For now I can retreive the data in row order using for loop and this is my code

```
for (i = 0; i < Array1 .length; i++) {
  for (x in Array1 [i]) {
    console.log(data from array);
  } 
}
```

My target here is for every array is I need to make it as a row for every col. for example `Array1` is fol `Col1` and also note that my arrays are fixed for each col. col3 and 4 are for ex. only

Comment: What If you have 5 arrays and 4 cols?

Comment: @Nardong Bagsik It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to get data from table into an array in row wise manner or something else?

Comment: Sidenote: The `in` operator is for objects, not arrays. `for (x in Array1 [i])` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Please see the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data in table columns don't usually change unlike they do in rows, I **highly** discourage managing table data by columns. It is best to do it by rows.

What I mean is to have `Row1 = [Data_A, Data_1];` and `Row2 = [Data_B, Data_2];` and so on, rather than how you had it set up.

```js
function CreateRow(data) {
  var tr = "<tr>"
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr += "<td>" + data[i] + "</td>";
  }

  tr += "</tr>"

  $('#table').append(tr);
}

function EditRow(data, rowIdx) {
  var tr = $('#table').children().eq(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr.children().eq(i).text(data[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
      <th>Col4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Data 0</td>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="CreateRow(['A','B','C','D'])">Create Row</button>
<button type="button" onclick="EditRow(['EditedData1','EditedData2', 'EditedData3', 'EditedData4'], 0)">Edit First Row</button>
```

(Pure Javascript snippet for those who are interested)

```js
function CreateRow(data) {
        var table = document.getElementById("table");
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]));
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }

        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    function EditRow(data, rowIdx) {
        var tr = document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tr")[rowIdx];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].innerHTML = data[i];
        }
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
            <th>Col4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Data 0</td>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="CreateRow(['A','B','C','D'])">Create Row</button>
<button type="button" onclick="EditRow(['EditedData1','EditedData2', 'EditedData3', 'EditedData4'], 0)">Edit First Row</button>
```

Comment: TYSM for the big effort and also I understand that it is not advisable to do like this.